# Algorithm for shortest list of words

Tags: c#, algorithm

The issue is as follows: the user provides a StartWord and EndWord string of X letters together with a list of strings that are also of length X (lets make it 4 but probably more)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string StartWord = "Spot";
    string EndWord = "Spin";
    List<string> providedList = new List<string>
                                {
                                "Spin", "Spit", "Spat", "Spot", "Span"
                                };
    List<string> result = MyFunc(StartWord, EndWord, providedList);
}

public List<string> MyFunc(string startWord, string endWord, List<string> input)
{
    ???
}
```

From the provided parameters I need to display to the user a result that comprises of the SHORTEST list of 4 letter words, starting with StartWord and ending with EndWord with a number of intermediate words that are to be found in the list, where each word differs from the previous word by PRECISELY one letter.

For example the above code should return a list of strings containing these elements: 
Spot(as FirstWord), 
Spit(only one letter is different from previous word), 
Spin (as EndWord)

A bad exapmle would be: Spot, Spat, Span, Spin (as it takes 3 changes compared to the above 2)

I have been looking at some matching algorithms and recursion, but I am not able to figure out how to go about this.

Thank you for any kind of help in advance.

Comment: Don't embed the solution inside the question - instead write an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: Istvan Nadj, I've rolled back you invalid edit - it is perfectly fine to post self-answer, but completely wrong to edit question with answer essentially making the question pointless. You can copy your edits from history - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44219717/revisions to new answer.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov - created an anwser

Answer (score 2):

Create a graph where the vertices are words, and an edge connects any two words that differ by one letter.

Do a breadth-first search, starting at the `StartWord`, looking for the shortest path to the `EndWord`.

---

Here is sample code for this solution in a different language (Python).  That may give you an even better pointer. :-)

```
def shortestWordPath (startWord, endWord, words):
    graph = {}
    for word in words:
        graph[word] = {"connected": []}
    for word in words:
        for otherWord in words:
            if 1 == wordDistance(word, otherWord):
                graph[word]['connected'].append(otherWord)
    todo = [(startWord,0)]
    while len(todo):
        (thisWord, fromWord) = todo.pop(0)
        if thisWord == endWord:
            answer = [thisWord, fromWord]
            while graph[ answer[-1] ]["from"] != 0:
                answer.append(graph[ answer[-1] ]["from"])
            answer.reverse()
            return answer
        elif "from" in graph[thisWord]:
            pass # We have already processed this.
        else:
            graph[thisWord]["from"] = fromWord
            for nextWord in graph[thisWord]["connected"]:
                todo.append([nextWord, thisWord])
    return None


def wordDistance (word1, word2):
    return len(differentPositions(word1, word2))

def differentPositions(word1, word2):
    answer = []
    for i in range(0, min(len(word1), len(word2))):
        if word1[i] != word2[i]:
            answer.append(i)
    for i in range(min(len(word1), len(word2)),
                   max(len(word1), len(word2))):
        answer.append(i)
    return answer

print shortestWordPath("Spot", "Spin",
    ["Spin", "Spit", "Spat", "Spot", "Span"])
```

Comment: It does sound good, but my problem is putting it to code, any chance for a snippet?

Comment: @IstvanNadj I offered a solution in a different language, which you can try to translate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using(please feel free to comment on the up and down side of it):

```
private List<List<string>> allWordSteps;
private string[] allWords;

public List<string> WordLadder(string wordStart, string wordEnd, string[] allWordsInput)
{
    var wordLadder = new List<string>() { wordStart };
    this.allWordSteps = new List<List<string>>() { wordLadder };
    allWords = allWordsInput;

    do
    {
        wordLadder = this.IterateWordSteps(wordEnd);
    }
    while (wordLadder.Count() == 0);

    return wordLadder;
}

private List<string> IterateWordSteps(string wordEnd)
{
    List<List<string>> allWordStepsCopy = this.allWordSteps.ToList();
    this.allWordSteps.Clear();
    foreach (var wordSteps in allWordStepsCopy)
    {
        var adjacent = this.allWords.Where(
            x => this.IsOneLetterDifferent(x, wordSteps.Last()) &&
                 !wordSteps.Contains(x));

        if (adjacent.Contains(wordEnd))
        {
            wordSteps.Add(wordEnd);
            return wordSteps;
        }

        foreach (var word in adjacent)
        {
            List<string> newWordStep = wordSteps.ToList();
            newWordStep.Add(word);
            this.allWordSteps.Add(newWordStep);
        }
    }

    return new List<string>();
}

private bool IsOneLetterDifferent(string first, string second)
{
    int differences = 0;
    if (first.Length == second.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
        {
            if (first[i] != second[i])
            {
                differences++;
            }
        }
    }

    return differences == 1;
}
```